# Databricks Koalas: use for loop to create new columns with conditions and dynamically name the new column based on the old column names

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, databricks, spark-koalas

Example dataset:

```
kdf = ks.DataFrame({"power_1": [50, 100, 150, 120, 18], 
                   "power_2": [50, 150, 150, 120, 18],
                   "power_3": [60, 100, 150, 120, 18],
                   "power_4": [150, 90, 150, 120, 18],
                   "power_30": [50, 60, 150, 120, 18]
                   })

df = pd.DataFrame({"power_1": [50, 100, 150, 120, 18], 
                   "power_2": [50, 150, 150, 120, 18],
                   "power_3": [60, 100, 150, 120, 18],
                   "power_4": [150, 90, 150, 120, 18],
                   "power_30": [50, 60, 150, 120, 18]
                   })
```

I know how to do it in pandas. Below are my codes:

```
cols = df.filter(regex='power_').columns
for col in cols:
    df[col] = pd.to_numeric(df[col],errors='coerce')
    df[col+'_Status']= ['OFF' if x<100 or np.isnan(x) else 'ON' for x in df[col]]
```

I can create the new columns one by one in Koalas using:

```
kdf = kdf.assign(power_1_Status=(kdf['power_1'].gt(100)).astype(int).map({0:'OFF',1:'ON'}))
```

But I don't know how to do it for all power columns because my dataset is really large with 50+ power columns and 1000+ other columns. I am using Databricks. I don't want to write 50+ lines of codes for all the power columns. My problem here is that I don't know how to dynamically add "_Status" to my original column name "power_1" in for loop in Koalas.
I tried for loop using similar pandas structure. Here is what I tried but failed.

```
for col in cols:
    kdf = kdf.assign(col+'Status'=(kdf[col].gt(100)).astype(int).map({0:'OFF',1:'ON'}))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a look at Koala's documentation and used some functions there that are similar to pandas', so give this a whirl and see if it works:

```
 #select columns you are interested in into a separate dataframe
 filtered = df.filter(like='power_')

 #drop the filtered columns from df
 df = df.drop(filtered.columns,axis=1)

 #do some cleanup
 filtered = (filtered
            .astype(int)
            .gt(100)
            .applymap(lambda x: 'OFF' if x==0 else 'ON')
            .add_suffix('_STATUS'))

 #hook back to original dataframe
 pd.concat([df,filtered],axis=1)
```

You might want to use a copy when creating the filtered dataframe; just a suggestion as I don't know what costs are associated with that on Koalas.

```
 power_1_STATUS power_2_STATUS  power_3_STATUS  power_4_STATUS  power_30_STATUS
0   OFF              OFF              OFF            ON               OFF
1   OFF               ON              OFF            OFF              OFF
2   ON                ON               ON            ON               ON
3   ON                ON               ON            ON               ON
4   OFF              OFF              OFF            OFF              OFF
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. But Koalas takes about 6.97 minutes to create these columns. Pandas only takes like 15.83 seconds.

Comment: not versed with koalas; a skim through the documentation points out that you can use pyspark's interface. so maybe give that a try and see if it improves the results.

Answer (score 0):

```
def function1(ss:pd.Series):
    col1=ss.lt(100)|ps.isna(ss)
    return ss.mask(col1,'OFF').where(col1,'NO')

kdf.filter(regex='power_').add_suffix("_Status").apply(function1)
```

out:

```
power_1_STATUS power_2_STATUS  power_3_STATUS  power_4_STATUS  power_30_STATUS
0   OFF              OFF              OFF            ON               OFF
1   OFF               ON              OFF            OFF              OFF
2   ON                ON               ON            ON               ON
3   ON                ON               ON            ON               ON
4   OFF              OFF              OFF            OFF              OFF
```